System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to Load 'System.Data.SqlClient' Assembly in .NET Project
I'm encountering a persistent issue with my .NET project in Visual Studio. Every time I start the program, I get an error stating that the specified version of the System.Data.SqlClient assembly cannot be found. If I add the requested version, the error reoccurs, but with a new version request. Here is the exact error message:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Additionally, this issue seems to arise specifically when calling a .NET Framework function from a .NET Standard library.
I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Checked Project Dependencies:
Ensured that the correct version of System.Data.SqlClient is referenced in the project.

Updated NuGet packages:
Updated all packages to their latest versions via the NuGet Package Manager.

Cleaned and rebuilt the project:
Used "Clean Solution" and "Rebuild Solution" options in Visual Studio.



For problems of this kind it is often very helpful to turn on fusion logging which will tell you where the system is looking for the file and which file specifically is missing.

@JohnWu It looks like the NuGet packages aren't compiling.
LOG: GAC lookup unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting to download new URL file:///C:/Users/rdiaz/Documents/Proyectos/MZC/ZMDI_64/bin/x64/Debug/System.Data.SqlClient.DLL.
file:///C:/Users/rdiaz/Documents/Proyectos/MZC/ZMDI_64/bin/x64/Debug/System.Data.SqlClient.EXE.
LOG: Attempted to download new URL file:///C:/Users/rdiaz/Documents/Proyectos/MZC/ZMDI_64/bin/x64/Debug/System.Data.SqlClient/System.Data.SqlClient.EXE.
LOG: All URLs attempted to be fetched without success.

Have you checked "Copy to Output Directory"? See this answer

@JohnWu I tried but I don´t have that option with nuget packages

I suggest you add a direct reference to it to your project, if it doesn't already have one.

I fixed adding this line inside PropertyGroup in csproj file.
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>


The error message indicates that the runtime is trying to find the System.Data.SqlClient assembly is in the wrong location and failing. This usually happens when the assembly binding is not correctly configured or the runtime cannot resolve the correct assembly version.
Install the Latest Version of System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.8.2. Check References in Visual Studio, ensure that System.Data.SqlClient is listed under "Assemblies" or "NuGet". Clean and Rebuild the Solution.
